# Getting average event duration

Tags: mysql

I am writing a query for getting average value of event duration for given period of time.
We might consider that we do have table with 2 columns:

```
start               | end
-----------------------------------------
2019-10-14 18:16:08 | null
2019-10-14 19:39:47 | 2019-10-14 23:28:17
2019-10-16 03:29:33 | 2019-10-16 03:31:08
2019-10-16 21:43:34 | 2019-10-17 02:07:31
```

The wanted behaviour would be to take avg. time for each day. The first row should be ignored, cuz the task is not finished - it might be still going / infinite. For second row we would get avg. time of

```
(2019-10-16 03:31:0 - 2019-10-16 03:29:33) + (2019-10-16 21:43:34 - 2019-10-16 23:59:59) / 2 -- 2 events only
```

And the for 17th day we would get 2:07:31.
So far I've got this query:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%d') AS time_label,
    AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end, start))) AS value
FROM
    time
GROUP BY start
```

which is not working as expected. I might add `WHERE` clause but it won't work. I've tested it on much bigger table.

Comment: You need to filter out ongoing events and you need to group by date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it almost right, by grouping by start it would only group the same date and time, but when you group by time_label, it takes the individual days with out the time

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%d') AS time_label,
    AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end, start))) AS value
FROM
    timetable
GROUP BY time_label
```

**Result**

```
| time_label | value |
| ---------- | ----- |
| 2019-10-14 | 13710 |
| 2019-10-16 | 7966  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uWQN3216kCpwAiLq1k4ypp/1)